# How can I SlideToogle in repeater with anchor or linkbutton?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater, anchor tag and div tag inside it. The anchor has a jquery which is doing slidetoggle. But for example if I have 5 items in repeater div count is also 5 and when I click the anchor all divs are doing slidetoggle.

If I use itemcommand it's ok, but this time js is not working. Because I'm using linkbutton and it has no click event as you know. So is there any solution to fix it?
Here is my repeater and js.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.4.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=aNotice]').click(function () {
                $('[id*=dvContent]').slideToggle(400);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptNotice" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="aNotice" runat="server">click to see toggle</a>
                    <div id="dvContent" runat="server"><%#Eval("content") %></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next` method:

```
$(function () {
     $('[id*=aNotice]').click(function () {
          $(this).next('div').slideToggle(400);
     });
});
```

Note that IDs must be unique and using `$('[id*=aNotice]')` is *overkill*, you should use classes instead.

```
$('.aNotice').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     $(this).next('div').slideToggle(400);
});
```

And also there is need to load jQuery UI twice, `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js` is just minified version of `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js`.

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But I have a question. If I use second js which is event.preventDefault() link is not working. But first one is ok now. Can you just explain what it is doing?

Comment: @kad1r You are welcome, you should pass  the `event` to the event handler.